# Replace UUID field content back to default null

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, uuid

Using `Django==2.2.27`, and Postgres

I have a Model, with a UUID field:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
  uuid_field = models.UUIDField(
    blank=True,
    db_index=True,
    null=True,
  )
```

I need to delete the field (column) content for some objects (rows) - but when I try:

```
my_object.uuid_field = None
my_object.save()
```

I get this error:

```
ValidationError: ["'None' is not a valid UUID."]
```

^ That makes sense, since the value is definitely not a UUID: [link](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c8459708a7e0a2474255b77d0f104a7f16e8b32c/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L2586)

A bit more explanation:

1. I can create objects without populating the `uuid_field` so it stays null
2. I will most likely populate the `uuid_field`
3. I might need to delete the `uuid_field` content
4. I cannot change the `UUIDField` to a char field or anything else

Is there a way to get the field back to its default null using Django ORM?
Thank you!

Comment: What about NULL instead of None ?

Comment: @FrankHeikens that will not work, similar to None. I am now going to try implementing a removal raw SQL getting the connection cursor: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly but I still hope for an ORM solution

Answer (score 0):

The non Django ORM solution I have is as such:

```py
from django.db import connection

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
  cursor.execute("UPDATE mymodelapp_mymodel SET uuid_field = null WHERE id = %s", [<MyModel id, int>])
```

I would love to get an ORM solution.

One thing I can do is to override `models.UUIDField` and customize it to behave as I would expect it to - but I am open to other ideas